# get data from phpmyadmin and move the progresss bar container according to the value

Tags: javascript, php

I have to move progress bar's container according to the value taking from phpmyadmin database.
I have tried code in js. Firstly I have fetch the data from phpmyadmin databse in php.and the data is also printing in array.

```
<div class="progress progress-bar-vertical">
    <div class="progress-bar" role="progress" id="progress" aria-valuenow="result" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="height: result%;"></div>

    <script>
    setInterval(function(){
        jQuery.ajax({
            url: "/bar1.php",
            success: function(result) {
                console.log(result);
                $('.progress-bar').css("height", result.responseText + '%');
            },
        });
    }, 1000);
    </script>
```

I just want to move the container of vertical progress bar according the values taking from the database.

Comment: And your problem is..?

Comment: Problem is containers are not moving according the values in bar graph.